# android spinner layout not visible and show middle white color after setting style

Tags: android, spinner

```
    <style name="CustomSpinner" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerDivideStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    </style>
```

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/login_fragment_server"
            android:theme="@style/CustomSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_spinner"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWHpd.png)

I don't know this situation...
I searching many custom spinner, they don't teach spinner visible error to me.
please how to custom spinner layout, and visible and remove method middle white color

Comment: Can you also add the code for ```@drawable/login_spinner``` and also ```@style/SpinnerDivideStyle```?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes, but is not removed white space, below my answer, remove white space after apply background color tranparent

Answer (score 1):

spinner style change

I solved !

```
<style>
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```